# Passing a class name and its variable as a parameter

Tags: laravel, request

```php
class A{
  public function show(Request $request){          

  }
}
```

what does `Request` and `$request` signify and how can we use them? Is it different from PHP object Aggregation in case of Laravel

Comment: To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request class on your controller method. its explained in the doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "PHP object Aggregation"?

Answer (score 1):

`Request` is a type hint. It means you expect a variable to be of the type `Request`. A Request in Laravel is an object that holds all the information relating to the HTTP request. From the object you can request all things related to the protocol, and then some. Laravel attaches a lot more information than just the HTTP request in a Request object: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

`$request` on the other hand is just the identifier of the parameter. If you do not know what a parameter is in php you might want to check some of the basics in PHP. In short, by using the arrow you can access properties and methods on the object: `$request->input('name')` Will return the name input if it was provided in the HTTP request.

Regarding object Aggregation: Request holds indeed many other objects, but I do not see how that relates to Laravel specifically.

Your example is a typical Controller pattern in laravel. You can use this object to tell Laravel you provided an object to handle the incoming Request. It is combined with another concept, called routing: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing